# Python inline in a js function doesn't works fine

Tags: javascript, python, forms, radio-button, tornado

I have a problem. I have this js function:

```
 <script>
function checkall(perm){

var permall = parseInt(perm);

if (permall==0) {
    {% for user in users %}
    document.getElementById("perms_{{user.id}}_0").checked=true
    document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();
    {% end %}}
else if (permall==1) {
    {% for user in users %}
    document.getElementById("perms_{{user.id}}_1").checked=true
    document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();
    {% end %}}
else if (permall==4) {
    {% for user in users %}
    document.getElementById("perms_{{user.id}}_4").checked=true
    document.forms['form_user_{{ user.id }}'].submit();
    {% end %}}

 }
</script>
```

When I click on a button I call this function, that for every user in a list of users, set to checked the user radio button of the relative permission and then submit the user form to set the permission in the DB (this calls an handler in Python).

Now, the code to set to checked the radio buttons works fine. But only the form of the first user in the list is submitted... The function set the permission only to the first user. Alse the Python handler is called only one time (I made some debug print).

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the `submit()` action of a form is exactly the same as if you've pressed the button yourself: the whole page will be refreshed with the response from the server (usually a redirect), so no more JS actions will be processed.

You'll need to serialize the values yourself and submit them via AJAX if you want to do multiple submissions at once.

Comment: how can I write the ajax request?

Comment: That's not something I can explain in a comment. Please read some Ajax tutorials - you might want to look into a library like jQuery which makes it quite simple - and then ask another question if you're still stuck.